# What are the pros and cons of a default URL with www or without www?

Tags: url, dns, openid

We need to default URL to unique name. If it is www then with no prefix or vice versa. So decision to be made is either stick with www or with no prefix.

**With no prefix cookie is set for all sub domains. What are other downsides for it? Or benefits?**

Basically we need this for OpenID as OpenID will make users look different if they came from www or with no prefix.

As our site is new so we can go with either one. Also, how the domain name looks is not much of a concern.

Comment: Who voted for this to be moved to superuser.com :D. silly person

Comment: This really isn't a programming question.  It's more a webmaster and/or server admin type of thing, and would be more on topic on doctype.com or maybe serverfault.com.  I haven't voted to close yet, but i might.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Technical/Programming/Non-SEO Pros and Cons of WWW or no-WWW?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839095/technical-programming-non-seo-pros-and-cons-of-www-or-no-www)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By **not** using the `www` subdomain, you can suffer a performance hit when delivering static content, as noted here: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free. As I understand it, if you use `http://example.com/` and `http://static.example.com` for static content, any cookies you set on the main domain will be passed with requests to your static subdomain.

This can be avoided quite easily, by buying a distinct domain for static content. However, this can certainly be dealt with by using a `www` subdomain.

Then again, this is a very minor con, and really only comes into play when you're dealing with a high-demand site. (For example, Digg uses `http://digg.com` and `http://*.diggstatic.com`).

Ultimately, I would say that this is such a minor problem that it can probably be dealt with if performance starts to suffer. Don't optimize prematurely, and all that...

And, as @Tomas Lycken points out, make sure you account for `www` even if you don't use the subdomain.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to redirect (with a `HTTP 301 - Permanent Redirect`) one to the other anyway, since maintaining consistent urls is much easier that way. So whichever you decide, just make sure the actual authentication is done *after* the redirect, and users looking different won't be an issue.

That said, if you want `www` or not depends entirely on how other things in your appliction works. You mention that cookies for `domain.com` will be saved for *all* subdomains - is this something you want? Are you ever going to need to differentiate (for example, by allowing users to set up their own authentication systems for subdomains as a shared hosting service might do)?

If none of the differences you find between including and excluding `www` matter to your application, I'd go for *not* using `www`. The main reason for this is my picture of current trends on the internet - more and more applications (SO is an example of this) tend to leave the `www` out, both when linking to their own sites, and in marketing of different kinds.

However, the main point is **make both work**. You **don't** want your site to break because the user did(n't) type `www` at the beginning of the url.