# No wwwin google websites like Google play

Tags: url, no-www

This may seem to be a stupid question 
But I recently noticed that some of the Google websites like Google play, Google drive have URL's which do not contain ' www' in them.

I'll be grateful if someone could explain the meaning of the parts of an URL

Thanx  :)

P. S. 
M a newbie in understanding how the Internet works.

Comment: There are no stupid questions (only stupid downvoters). As for `www` that is just a convention. You can name your domain whatever you want. See some discussion about pros and cons here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406740/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-a-default-url-with-www-or-without-www?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question has already been asked in superuser (SE metasite):

https://superuser.com/questions/60006/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-www-subdomain

Comment: added as answer - I don't know how to flag a post as duplicate of another SE community - recommend to move etc.. ? is this possible?