# Httpd.conf: Set Cookie Only On http:// not http://sub.domain.com

Tags: wordpress, cookies, seo, subdomain

I am trying to get rid of cookies. For SEO reasons I do not want to rewrite my domain to www.domain.com.

That's why I would like to know if it would be possible to make Wordpress/Apache set cookies only to http://domain.com and not on subdomains without rewriting to www.

I would even be willing to pay for this .. if you have any idea how to achieve it.

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having gone through this dilemma myself over the last year my answer(s) are:

1. [There is NO good SEO reason ***not*** to use www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839095/technical-programming-non-seo-pros-and-cons-of-www-or-no-www)
2. Setting cookies to `http://example.com` [impacts ALL sub-domains](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) - including '`www`'. AFAIK there is no way around this.

I'd seriously (!) consider how dogmatic your approach to point 1 is before investing time/energy/money in overcoming point 2.