# What's the difference between a "GET" request and a "page refresh"?

Tags: http, browser, httprequest

Is there any difference between doing a "GET" request (type URL and <kbd>Enter</kbd>) compared to simply refreshing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers ignore the [Expires header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) if we do a "page refresh", yet respect it if we do a "url visit".

However, different browsers have their own way of differentiating "refresh" and "url visit", the only way to be sure is to manually test each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not simply a get request, because on a page that you've POSTed to (from a separate form), the browser will confirm with you that you want to refresh the page because it is a POST request.

As for your question, you'll need to provide specifics for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply telling the browser to repeat the page load, which implies repeating the GET or POST request. Some browsers will inform the server that 304 (not-modified) is an acceptable response, and the server can reply with a 304 HTTP response to inform the browser that it's cached contents are valid